# Unable to connect to mysql server because of "java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server"

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-connector

Here is the code which i use to connect to the server:

```
String records = "",error="";
        void connectToDatabase() {
            try {
                String ip = "";//mysql server ip(removed due to privacy reasons)
                Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + ip +":3306/androiddb?user=andro&password=andro");
                Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM mainTable");
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    records += resultSet.getString(1) + " " + resultSet.getString(2) + "\n";
                }
                System.out.println(records);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                error = e.toString();
                System.out.println(error);
            }
        }
```

Exception i get:

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
```

my.ini file:

```
[mysqld]
basedir=C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0
datadir=C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\data
bind-address = *mysql server ip*
```

I use mysql server 8.0.24 and jdbc 8.0.24

UPD: I don't know why but it started to work after i installed jdbc 5.0.41

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error with MySQL 8.0.23 and jdbc connector 8.0.24. It seems to me that the connection is successful by adding the params `&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=GMT%2B9:00&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&connectionTimeZone=SERVER' at the string. See the Release Notes for details.

- [MySQL :: MySQL Connector/J 8.0 Release Notes :: Changes in MySQL Connector/J 8.0.23 (2021-01-18, General Availability)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/8.0/en/news-8-0-23.html)

I hope it is helpful.